# Pushing a button programmatically to submit a form on another page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please forgive the basic question, I'm very new to Javascript and web development in general. I want to use a script on one page of my site to programmaticaly press a button to submit a form on another part of the site, making a `POST` request. The `html` I have to access is the following:

**html**

```
<form action="thing.jsp" method="post"> // Beginning of form
...
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Do something"> // Button code
...
</form>
```

And I think the `Javascript` should look something like this:

**JS**

```
   <script>

       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('POST', "/stuff.jsp", true);
       var params = "???????"; // What do I need to put here?
       xhr.send(params);

    </script>
```

From reading around online, my suspicion is that I may just need to get the right value for `params`? Though if there's another way of achieving the same result (e.g. by just sending a `POST` request without doing anything to the button), I'd be perfectly happy to go with that.

Thanks in advance for your time and wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use ajax, just use this:

```
<input type="button" value="GO" id="buttonId" />
<script>
function go() {
    document.location.href = 'http://google.com';
}

document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = go;
</script>
```

please notice the button type should be 'button', not 'submit'

Comment: That looks like what I need, but it's giving me an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at window.onload (myPage.html:20)`. Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: probably getElementById couldn't find the element. Check if the element has an id attribute, and if you spelled getElementById correctly. obviously 'buttonId' should be replaced by your element's id.

Comment: Checked for typos. `id="submit"` like in the example code I gave and that's what I replaced the `buttonid` in your code with. Also tried wrapping the whole thing in a `window.onload = function() {};`. Just to double check that I haven't explained myself too badly: what I'm looking for is a script one page of a site which will submit a form on another page of the site.

Comment: I know the problem. change your button type to 'button' instead of 'submit'. Please notice I'm saying to change the type attribute, not the id.

Comment: Thanks. That's answered the question I asked. Would be better if I could manage it without having to change the input type, though. Will see if I can work one out.

Comment: You can do it without changing input type. Just add a `return false;` to the go function. That will prevent the default action of submitting the form. But in this case the type would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) - a JS library - you can simply send a [HTTP GET Request](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp). This can then be picked up in PHP using `$_GET['key']` which will hold the value.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#unique-id-btn').click(function() {
    $.get('file.php', { key: $('unique-id-input').val() }).done(function(response) {
      alert(response);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="unique-id-input" placeholder="enter something...">
<button type="button" id="unique-id-btn">Click me</button>
```

Note, you will need to create the *file.php*. Inside, it will control what happens with that data being sent across, ie:

```
$data = $_GET['key'];
echo $data == "foo" ? "bar" : "tell me foo!";
```

Also note you can only run PHP in a **.php** file extension, not JSP.